# MCMC Python Code Question

Tags: mathematical-statistics, python, markov-chain-montecarlo

I have a question about Python coding of a simple MCMC exercise. I wanted to visualize the transition matrix obtained from MCMC simulation. However, according to the following code, every entry is zero except one which has value 1. It means that the markov chain only visited a single state throughout the entire simulation, and thus my MCMC algorithm seems not working properly. So I was hoping if you guys could spot some mistake here. Thank you so much!! Below is my code:

````
 
import numpy as np 

from scipy.stats import norm, invgamma

# Set the true values of mu and sigma
mu_true = 5.0 

sigma_true = 2.0

# Generate some data
n = 10000

data = np.random.normal(mu_true, sigma_true, n)

# Set the prior distribution for mu and sigma
mu_prior_mean = 0.0

mu_prior_std = 10.0

mu_prior = norm(mu_prior_mean, mu_prior_std)

sigma_prior_shape = 2.0

sigma_prior_scale = 1.0

sigma_prior = invgamma(sigma_prior_shape, scale=sigma_prior_scale)

# Number of Iterations for the MCMC algorithm
n_iterations = 10000

# Set the initial values for mu and sigma
mu_current = 0.0

sigma_current = 1.0

# Initialize the transition matrix
n_states = 50

transition_matrix = np.zeros((n_states, n_states))

# Run the MCMC algorithm and record the transitions

for i in range(n_iterations):
    # Generate proposal values for mu and sigma
    mu_proposal = np.random.normal(mu_current, 0.1)
    sigma_proposal = sigma_current * np.random.uniform(0.9, 1.1)
    
    # Calculate the likelihood of the data given the proposed values of mu and sigma
    likelihood_proposal = np.prod(norm.pdf(data, loc=mu_proposal, scale=sigma_proposal))
    likelihood_current = np.prod(norm.pdf(data, loc=mu_current, scale=sigma_current))
    
    # Calculate the prior probabilities of the proposed and current values of mu and sigma
    prior_proposal = mu_prior.pdf(mu_proposal) * sigma_prior.pdf(sigma_proposal)
    prior_current = mu_prior.pdf(mu_current) * sigma_prior.pdf(sigma_current)
    
    # Calculate the Metropolis-Hastings acceptance ratio
    acceptance_ratio = (likelihood_proposal * prior_proposal) / (likelihood_current * prior_current)
    
    # Accept or reject the proposed values of mu and sigma
    if acceptance_ratio >= 1 or np.random.uniform() < acceptance_ratio:
        mu_current = mu_proposal
        sigma_current = sigma_proposal
    
    # Record the transition in the transition matrix
    mu_index = int((mu_current - mu_prior_mean) / mu_prior_std * n_states / 2 + n_states / 2)
    sigma_index = int(np.log(sigma_current / sigma_prior_scale) * n_states / np.log(20) + n_states / 2)
    if mu_index >= 0 and mu_index < n_states and sigma_index >= 0 and sigma_index < n_states:
        transition_matrix[mu_index, sigma_index] += 1

# Normalize the transition matrix to obtain transition probabilities
sums = np.sum(transition_matrix, axis=1, keepdims=True)
transition_matrix = np.divide(transition_matrix, np.where(sums == 0, 1, sums))

# Plot the transition matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(transition_matrix, origin='lower', cmap='Blues', extent=[-10, 10, 0, 20])
plt.xlabel('mu')
plt.ylabel('sigma')
plt.title('Transition matrix')
plt.show()
```
````

Comment: A transition _matrix_ for continuous target and proposal???

Comment: I tried to discretizie the states, but would it be a problem?